# How do I access and print individual elements of a vector of vectors?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I tried building a 7*3 matrix, and then printing it's elements as it's values are initialized, but unfortunately the program terminates when run. If there is a simpler,more efficient way of doing the same process, please do tell.

```
vector< vector<int> >  v1;
for(int i = 0;i < 7;i++)
{
    for(int j = 0;j < 3;j++)
    {
        v1[i].push_back(i + j);
        cout << v1[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: "Terminates"? As in an exception or error? Show us...

Comment: Remember that vectors start out empty, and all indexing in them is out of bounds. Start by pushing back a `vector<int>` into the outer vector.

Comment: @MordechayS Well,it compiles without any problem, but when I run the program it displays "Process returned -1073741819<0xC0000005>"

Comment: A vector of vectors is just a vector. So figure out how to fill a vector and access its elements first.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried your method and it works! But doesn't additional pushing back slow down performance? Do you suppose there is any other way to do this without affecting the performance?

Comment: Measure. Always measure if you think something will be slow. In most cases it's not as slow as one think is is, or possible "inefficiencies" are negligible compared to other places in the program. In your case it will barely be measurable, especially if you build with C++11 (or later) mode enabled which allows moving instead of copying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forget to initialize `v1`.

You may use the following:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v1(7, std::vector<int>(3));
for (int i = 0; i != 7; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j != 3; ++j) {
        v1[i][j] = i + j;
    }
}

// Display
for (const auto& row : v1) {
    for (const auto& e : row) {
        std::cout << e << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Can I also initialize v1 with variables?

Comment: Note sure exactly what you mean, but you can initialize `v1` a lot of way as `std::vector<std::vector<int>> v1 {{1, 2, 3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{10,11,12},{13,14,15},{16,17,18},{19,20,21}};`

Comment: For instance let's say: int N = 7,x=3;Now can I initialize v1 as std::vector<std::vector<int>> v1(N, std::vector<int>(x));

Comment: Yes, you can initialize the size of the vector with runtime value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put an empty `vector<int>` into `v1` before using `v1[x]`:

```
vector< vector<int> >  v1;
for(int i = 0;i < 7;i++)
{
    v1.push_back(vector<int>());
    for(int j = 0;j < 3;j++)
    {
        v1[i].push_back(i + j);
        cout << v1[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Type `vector< vector<int> > v1;` is somehow confusing but two vector has different meanings. First one is to define a type of `v1` and, at this point, `v1` becomes an empty vector. Instead of this, second vector just means that a type that `v1` can hold. Thus, when defining this, `v1` is ready to use however `v1[x]` have not created yet at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code crashes quite obviously.
Try this:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> >  v1;
for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
{
    v1.push_back(std::vector<int>());
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {
        v1[i].push_back(i + j);
        std::cout << v1[i][j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

EDIT: Ok... Already answered, too late ;-)

Comment: well... it's obvious it's not obvious for him, otherwise he wouldn't have asked here